# How can I specify where yepnope.js places a loaded script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yepnope

Im' a bit of a JS noob.

This is a rough example but it illustrates my issue. yepnope is working great but it is adding the yep script (jquery.selectBoxIt.min.js) at the top of the stack. Issue is if the loaded script is put to the top of the stack it loads before the JQuery library. Problem is it dependes on jQuery in order to run. I looked through the yepnope docs but I didn't see anything mention of it.

Here is my code (at the bottom of my document:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.infieldlabel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Modernizr.load([
    {
    // Let's check something simple
    test : Modernizr.borderradius,
    // this should then satisfy the yep and load this script
    yep : ['js/jquery.selectBoxIt.min.js']
    }
]);
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Why don't you just add that javascript file into the script file?

Comment: @Shawn31313 why do "we" need to load extra information if we don't use it? if the browser does not support `borderradius`, it will not load more stuff...

Comment: Shawn do you mean combine them all? I normally would but this is a fairly complex multi-step application that I will be handing off to someone else when I am done so I want to make it easy at this point for the next guy.

Comment: Yes. I would just has the js/jquery.selectBoxIt.min.js in it's own `<script>` tag. But oh okay.

Comment: @balexandre That's exactly right. Also borderradius was just for testing. I will probably in the end test .no-touch to test for mobile. Thats my end goal.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the above static JS code in a function and put it in $(document).ready() - This will ensure that jquery is loaded by the time the script is called. If this is not feasible, try loading jquery using javascript and in the callback place the static JS. Refer [Load jQuery dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212809/load-jquery-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

to do it without jquery:

```
function init(){
  Modernizr.load([
  {
  test : Modernizr.borderradius,
  yep : ['js/jquery.selectBoxIt.min.js']
  }
  ]);
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false)
```

Comment: Plato thanks for this. Unfortunately it is still loading the selectBoxIt script as the first one.

Comment: By the time the DOMContentLoaded event fires, jQuery (and every other script you placed in your HTML) has definitely loaded. I would check your scripts carefully to make sure you aren't overwriting $ or something.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to Modernizr/yepnope myself, but from [the yepnode docs](http://yepnopejs.com/) I believe the key is to use yepnope (or Modernizr, they're the same thing) to load the scripts you need in the right order, and yepnope will ensure they are executed in the order you specify.

So I believe that what you need is something like this:

```
<script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">   

Modernizr.load([
    {
        // Load jQuery first
        load : ['js/jquery.js', 
                // ... and your other JS files
               ]
    },
    {
        // Let's check something simple
        test : Modernizr.borderradius,
        // this should then satisfy the yep and load this script
        yep : ['js/jquery.selectBoxIt.min.js']
    }
]);

</script>
```

Also check out those yepnode docs for the example where they try to load jquery from a CDN, and fall back to a local copy if it doesn't load successfully - that made it clearer to me.