# jQuery: why click event works only once?

Tags: jquery, popup, onclicklistener

I am using jQuery click event handler to add click event to all anchor tags present in my HTML.
But click event works only once. Basically onclick action I am displaying one popup, which gets displayed for only once. if i click it again it does not displayed.

Below is my code:

```
function onClickLoginPopup (anchor)
{
    var url = anchor.href;
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var mainPopup = $('#popupMain');



    if (mainPopup.length == 0 && mainPopup.is(":visible") == false) 
    {
        // load popup.css
        var styleSheet = document.createElement('link');
        styleSheet.href = 'http://192.168.1.6:8080/OtherDomain/css/mpw.css?' + new Date();
        styleSheet.rel = "stylesheet";
        head.appendChild(styleSheet);


        $.ajax({
          url: "http://192.168.1.6:8080/OtherDomain/popup.html",
          data: '',
          cache: false,
          success: function(data){
              document.body.innerHTML += data;
              if($('#popupMain').length > 0) {
                  alert('ShowPopup');
                  showPopup();
              }
          }                                      
        });

    }   
}

function addClickEventListenerToAllAnchorTag()
{
        var anchors =  document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++)
        {
            var anchor = anchors[i];
            //console.log(anchor);

                anchors[i].addEventListener("click",function(event)
                {
                    console.log(this.href + ' clicked');
                    onClickLoginPopup(anchor);
                }, false);              
        }   

}

function initialize(){
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var host = "192.168.1.6";
    var server = "http://" + host + ":8080/OtherDomain/";

    var req = document.createElement("script");
    req.src = server + "js/jquery.js?" + new Date();
    req.type = "text/javascript";
    head.appendChild(req);

    // load Popup.js
    var popupJs = document.createElement("script");
    popupJs.type = 'text/javascript';
    popupJs.src = "http://192.168.1.6:8080/OtherDomain/js/Popup.js?" + new Date();
    head.appendChild(popupJs);
    addClickEventListenerToAllAnchorTag();  
}

window.onload = initialize;
```

Here on window.onload I am calling initialize function which basically loads my popup script and jQuery and it is calling addClickEventListenerToAllAnchorTag() function which is just fetching all anchor tags from HTML and adding click event listener to it. Inside that I am calling onClickLoginPopup() function which is ajax call to fetch remote element. There in showPopup() mehtod calls below code:

Popup.js

```
 function showPopup() {
        console.log('In showPopup');
        //$('#popupMain').show();
        document.getElementById('popupMain').style.display = 'block';
    }
```

But somehow this popup is getting displayed only once and fails to display on subsequent clicks.
Please help.

Comment: What is the value of `mainPopup.is(":visible")`  when you click it second time ?

Comment: What a horrific mix of DOM and jQuery. Also I suspect you need to add preventDefault to the anchors

Comment: @mininoz second time function does not get called

Comment: @mplungjan added preventDefault but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you are creating script tags from javascript? Why not create them in the head right away?

I suggest looking into jQuery a bit more. There is so much unnecessary code.

```
function addClickEventListenerToAllAnchorTag()
{
        var anchors =  document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++)
        {
            var anchor = anchors[i];
            //console.log(anchor);

                anchors[i].addEventListener("click",function(event)
                {
                    console.log(this.href + ' clicked');
                    onClickLoginPopup(anchor);
                }, false);              
        }   

}
```

can be jQueryfied to

```
$(function(){
    $("a").click(onClickLoginPopup);
});
```

and onClickLoginPopup to something like this:

```
function onClickLoginPopup (ev)
{
    ev.preventDefault();
    var $mainPopup = $("#popupMain");

    if (!$mainPopup.filter(":visible").length) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://192.168.1.6:8080/OtherDomain/popup.html",
          data: '',
          cache: false,
          success: function(data){
              $("body").append(data);
              if($('#popupMain').length) {
                  showPopup();
              }
          }                                      
        });

    }   
}
```

I wouldn't load the css in the click handler either. Because the way you do it now, would create a new link tag each time you show the popup. You could also think about appending the popup html right away at the end of the body and just show/hide it when needed, that way you wouldn't need the ajax call at all.

Comment: Is this not almost the same answer as mine? Except where you insert the popup if it is not visible...

Comment: @Andy I am creating script tag from javascript because that needs to be dynamically added

Comment: @mahendrakawde ok, in that case you could take a look at https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Comment: @Andy i can see  $("body").append(data);
data appended to a body as well as its style is display:block.
But cant see it on screen

Comment: @mahendrakawde Could be because I left out the CSS creation in my example!? Hard to tell without seeing the page.

Comment: @Andy  that worked out nicely.
But one more question.
Right now i added jQuery in the head right away.
But i need to add it dynamically using javascipt.

Comment: @mahendrakawde http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212809/load-jquery-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery USE jQuery and if you execute script on click of anchors, cancel the click.

```
function onClickLoginPopup(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel link
    var url = this.href;
    var $head = $('head');
    var $mainPopup = $('#popupMain');
    if ($mainPopup.length == 0) { // it cannot be visible if it is not there
        // load popup.css
      $head.append('<link>',{href:"http://"+host+"/OtherDomain/css/mpw.css?" + new Date().getTime(),rel:"stylesheet"});
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://"+host+":8080/OtherDomain/popup.html",
          data: '',
          cache: false,
          success: function(data){
              $("body").append(data);
              if($('#popupMain').length > 0) {
                  showPopup();
              }
          }                                      
        });
    }   
}


var host = "...";
$(function(){
    var $head = $("head");
    var server = "http://" + host + ":8080/OtherDomain/";
    $head.append('<script></script>',{src:server + "js/jquery.js?" + new Date().getTime()});

    // load Popup.js
    $head.append("http://"+host+":8080/OtherDomain/js/Popup.js?" + new Date().getTime()});

  // if there are no link in the appended data use this

   $("a").each(function() {
     $(this).on("click",onClickLoginPopup);
   });  

  // else use this
  $(document).on("click","a",onClickLoginPopup);

});
```